# Django admin shows full path to uploaded file, and link contains full path. How can I fix this?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model which is defined like this:

```
class Attachment(models.Model):
  file            = models.FileField(upload_to=MEDIA_ROOT)
```

MEDIA_ROOT is defined using it's absolute path, and it's something like d:\django\my_proj\media . In the admin, the link to it appears like this: http://localhost:8000/media/d:/django/my_proj/media/file.txt . How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/` instead of `MEDIA_ROOT`. From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to), `upload_to` should be:

> A local filesystem path that will be
>   appended to your MEDIA_ROOT setting to
>   determine the value of the url
>   attribute.

In other words, the path that you specify in `upload_to` will be appended to `MEDIA_ROOT` to form the upload directory, and appended to `MEDIA_URL` to form the URL to the file.

p.s. it might be worth specifying a subdirectory instead of `/` just so the uploaded files cannot overwrite your media files. For example, `upload_to='uploads/'`. To organise you uploads by year/month, you can even do `upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/'`. See docs for more details.

Comment: Thank you, I went with the uploads approach.